# Python list of identical sublists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to programmatically create a list containing `n` identical sublists:

```
>>> pos = [10,20]
>>> 3 * pos
[10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20]
```

But what I want is `[[10,20], [10,20], [10,20]]`

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[[10, 20] for _ in range(3)]
```

There is also the option to use multiplication:

```
[[10, 20]] * 3   # or [pos] * 3
```

but that creates a list of 3 references to the *same nested list*:

```
>>> lis = [[10, 20]] * 3
>>> lis[0][0] = 'foo'
>>> lis
[['foo', 20], ['foo', 20], ['foo', 20]]
```

which is usually not what you want. The list comprehension re-evaluates the expression on the left hand side (the part before the `for` expression) for each loop iteration and that creates a *new* list for each index in the outer list:

```
>>> lis = [[10, 20] for _ in range(3)]
>>> lis[0][0] = 'foo'
>>> lis
[['foo', 20], [10, 20], [10, 20]]
```

If you want to use a list stored in a variable to repeat, make sure you *create a copy* on each iteration:

```
[pos[:] for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: In my answer because I used `pos` is it = `pos *3` **??**

Comment: Thanks, I like the underscore for ignoring the variable in the list comprehension.. is that your own style or is that common?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: You'd be looking at `[pos] * 3`, but you want to avoid that.

Comment: @trideceth12: It is a common pattern to indicate that the loop variable is going to be ignored.

Answer (score 9):

```
[[10, 20] for x in range(3)]
```

beware of

```
[[10, 20]] * 3
```

because it copies the same list 3 times